# Turning an AWS credentials CSV into an object

Tags: ruby, csv, vagrant

I am using the following code in Ruby

```
require 'csv'
CSV.foreach('credentials/sns.csv', :headers => true, :col_sep => ',') do | row |
  SNS.create(:IAM => row['IAM User Name'], :KEY => row['Smtp Username'], :SECRET => row['Smtp Password'])
end
```

and would expect at this point in Vagrant I could use

```
config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "scripts/bootstrap.sh", :args => [SNS.KEY, SNS.SECRET]
```

But end up with an `Message: uninitialized constant SNS`

This is evidently NOT the way to do this, so what am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

The way that I learned this was from [This blog post](http://railsguides.net/parse-csv-with-column-names/)

Comment: What is the SNS object? (where is it defined?) Is it being pulled in via a require? (module, class?)

If it's a real sns client, you probably need to require 'aws-sdk'

Comment: No its just something I made to store the values

Comment: are both things in the same script? (i.e. vagrant script)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example you provided assumes that there is a Car class that has a create method + getters for the properties.

If both snippets are in the same file (vagrant config), one way to go about this would be:

```
SNS = {}
require 'csv'
CSV.foreach('credentials/sns.csv', :headers => true, :col_sep => ',') do | row |
  SNS[:IAM]=row['IAM User Name']
  SNS[:KEY]=row['Smtp Username']
  SNS[:SECRET]=row['Smtp Password']
end

config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "scripts/bootstrap.sh", :args => [SNS[:KEY], SNS[:SECRET]]
```